# Adjust Value of a different Select after remoteFunction using update

Tags: jquery, grails

I'm looking to change the selected value of a separate 'g:select' in an 'update' or 'onSuccess' after a remote function that happens in an onChange.

GSP Code:

```
<g:select name="mainSelect"
                                  id="mainSelect"
                                  from="${mainSelect}"
                                  value="${mSelect}"
                                  optionKey="key"
                                  optionValue="value"
                                  onchange="${remoteFunction (
                                            controller: 'mainController',
                                            action: 'checkValue',
                                            params: '\'value=\' + this.value + \'&value2=\' + otherSelect.value',
                                            onSuccess: '$("#otherSelect").val(data)',
                                  )}"
                                  noSelection="['': '']"/>
<g:select name="otherSelect"
                              id="otherSelect"
                              from="${notimportant}"
                              value="${notimportant2}"
                              optionKey="key"
                              optionValue="value" />
```

The remoteFunction "checkValue" renders "Y" or "N" dependent on a few variables, I've logged it out to know that this is definitely what it is returning every time. I just can't seem to get the dropdown to change after this. My post doesn't return any errors, I only get errors dependent on what is in the onSuccess or update.

I've tried multiple things like:

```
onSuccess: '$("#otherSelect").val(data)',
```

or

```
update: 'otherSelect'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.grails.org/3.0.0.M1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html

> onSuccess (optional) - The JavaScript function to call if successful

Just had to make a JS Function to plug into the onSuccess, as direct Javascript didn't want to work. Instead of the onSuccess above:

```
onSuccess: 'functionForSelect(data)',
```

The Function:

```
function functionForSelect(option)
{
  document.getElementById("otherSelect").value = option;
}
```